# ApiController does not receive Identity info from HttpRequest (Razor)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

It is my first time to use ASP.NET core 2.2 Identity to manage Authorization in Controller.  In the client side, I use (Login.cshtml.cs) SignInManger.PasswordSignInAsync(…) to sign in a user.  After user sign in successfully, I send HttpClient call to UsersController in another project to get more user’s info.   However, the Controller is does not receive the the Claims.ClaimsPrincipal (User)  information from the Request. The [Authorize(Roles = “admin”)] fails but [AllowAnonymous] passes. I checked the Request cookie.  The User HttpContext is not updated to the signed in user in client side.  To be exact, I don’t know how to update the User in cookie. I thought it is done in the background.  I have looked through many posts but none of them explicitly mentions how the User is being updated in the cookie and send to the controller.  It seems that the User updated is done after the program exits the Login.cshtml.cs. I am able to get the Identity of the user by using SingInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(…) within public async Task OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null) of Login.cshtml.cs.  But I don’t know how to pass that Identity to the User in cookie and send it to Controller.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            // test: get the Identity of the Input.Email
            var user = await _signInManager.UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
            var userPrincipal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);
            var identity = userPrincipal.Identity;

            // * User Identity does not populate at this point.
            var ret = await GetRestOfUserInfo();
        }
    }
    return Page();
}



private async Task<int> GetRestOfUserInfo()
{
    var userStatus = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

    UserCSDto userCDDto = new UserCSDto()
    {
        Email = Input.Email,
        UserName = Input.Email,
        Password = Input.Password,
        RememberMe = Input.RememberMe
    };

    CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        UseCookies = true,
        UseDefaultCredentials = true,
        CookieContainer = cookieContainer
    };

    var client = new HttpClient(handler);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userCDDto), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var url = _connectionSettings.UrlConnection + "/api/users/authenticate";
    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var respUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

        var _responseToken = response.Headers.Where(t => t.Key == "Authorization")
            .Select(t => t.Value);
        var token = (_responseToken.FirstOrDefault()).FirstOrDefault();

        applicationUser.PreferredName = respUser.PreferredName;
        applicationUser.Token = token;

        ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);

        user.Token = token;
        user.PreferredName = respUser.PreferredName ?? "";
        IEnumerable<Claim> claims = new Claim[]
        {
                          new Claim("Token", token),
                          new Claim("PreferredName", "123abc")        // respUser.PreferredName)
        };
        await _userManager.AddClaimsAsync(user, claims);

        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}


[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private IUserService _userService;


    public UsersController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
                           SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }

    :
    :

    [Authorize(Roles = "any role")]     // failed because User does not contain any info
    [AllowAnonymous]                // works because no authorization check
    [HttpPost("authenticate")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Authenticate([FromBody]UserCSDto userParam)
    {
        var username = User.Identity.Name;    // username is null because User does not 
                                              // have info.

        var user = _userService.Authenticate(userParam.UserName, userParam.Password);

        if (user == null)
            return BadRequest(new { message = "Username or passwrod is incorrect" });

        var token = _jwtTokenService.CreateToken(userCSDto);

        Response.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

        return Ok(userCSDto);
    }

    :
    :
   }

/////////////////////////////

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
        services.Configure<ConnectionSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
        var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

        services.AddDbContext<EFCoreContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(connection,
                b => b.MigrationsAssembly("EFStructures")));        // from Data project

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();  // #.Net Core 2.2

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;

        });

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.Name = "Test.Session";
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
            options.Cookie.Path = "/";
        });

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Password settings.
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

            // Lockout settings.
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

            // User settings.
            options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

            // Require Confirmed and Unique Email
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
        });

        #region authenication using JWT token
        services.Configure<JwtTokenSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("JwtTokenSettings"));

        ///// configure jwt authentication
        var jwtTokenSettings = Configuration.GetSection("JwtTokenSettings").Get<JwtTokenSettings>();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jwtTokenSettings.Secret);

        //Adds cookie middleware to the services collection and configures it
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options => options.LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login"));

        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                    //ValidateIssuer = Configuration["AppSettings:Issuer"],
                    //ValidateAudience = Configuration["AppSettings:Issuer"],
                    ValidateLifetime = true
            };
        });
        #endregion

        #region Add Role services to Identity RAZOR PAGE only
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
             //  .AddDefaultUI(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
             .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
             .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
             .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<EFCoreContext>();
        #endregion

        #region Setting for using Identity
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        #endregion Setting for using Identity

        services.AddHttpClient();

        services.AddScoped<IJwtTokenService, JwtTokenService>();
        services.AddScoped<IEmailSenderService, EmailSenderService>();
        services.AddScoped<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

        #region Get EmailSettings from appsettings.json
        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<EmailSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"));
        #endregion Get EmailSettings from appsettings.json

        services.AddMvc()
        .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
        {
            options
              .SuppressUseValidationProblemDetailsForInvalidModelStateResponses = true;
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseRequestLocalization();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

        // global cors policy
        app.UseCors(x => x
            .WithOrigins("https://localhost")
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Comment: "HttpClient call to UsersController" and why exactly do you think that HTTP call will include Cookies from the current application? That's a dangerously wrong assumption

Comment: In the GetRestOfUserInfo() {…}, I created a CookieContainer and add it to the HttpClientHandler.  The new HttpClient() takes the handler.  In what way I can add the Identity of current user and send it to the UserController for authorization checking?

Comment: You have 2 applications, one uses Cookies and the other uses JWTs. Either you get a JWT when you sign in to the front-end application or, better yet, put them in the same application if they are so related

Comment: I put both Cookies and JWT at services.AddAuthentication(…) so either one or both will be examined by controller.  The question is still I am missing the user identity in the transmission so I can't do the authorize in the controller.  The ApiController and front-end-application (web base) are closely related as you have noticed.  However, the ApiController is going to be used by mobile apps in the future.  So, I would rather to have the ApiController be separated.

Comment: There is one thing that can help. Where you write `// * User Identity does not populate at this point.` that's because `User.Identity` is a shortcut to `Request.User.Identity` and, as you can imagine, if you are logging in, the user *cannot* (normally) be already logged-in in the request. You have to either do not depend on the Identity or end the request (send OK to the client) and do another request

Comment: This line:  var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false); sign the user into the system.  However, the User Identity won't populate until the program exists the current function or return to other page. I have tried using your method by calling another page to submit request to controller, the User Identity is still missing.  I believe I am missing something that enable the User Identity passing into the controller for checking authorization.